# How many Model relation we can have in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller

I try to add Model Relation on Laravel. I know how we can make this but I don't understand, I can link all Model I need.

So this is my problem :

I build a exam system and it's work like this :

Evaluation -> Examid -> QuestionCategory -> Question -> Response.

So in Evaluation session, We choose a Examen which has question categories, which has questions, which has response.

So I wrote this :

```
public function testtheorique($session){
    $eval = Evaluation::find($session);
    $caces = $eval->caces_cat;
    $theorique = $eval->theorique;
    $questioncat = $theorique->examcategory;
    $question = $questioncat->categoryQuestions;
}
```

And this is my Models :

```
//Evaluation Model
public function theorique(){
        return $this->belongsTo(TestTheorique::class);
    }


//TestThorique Model
public function examcategory(){
        return $this->hasMany(QuestionCategorie::class, 'exam_id');
    }


//QuestionCategory Model
public function categoryQuestions(){
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class, 'category_id', 'id');
    }


//Question Model
 public function qcategory(){
        return $this->belongsTo(QuestionCategorie::class);
    }
```

So when I make this dd($eval) I have all the data displayed with the relationships but only up to the examcategory. I can't display the Question because I don't have relation.

So I don't know how I can have the question relation. I can't see where I made an error.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you tell each of your model is linked with foreign key or not?

Comment: Yes when is necessary. I don't know how I can't display the question. I have this error message : Property [categoryQuestions] does not exist on this collection instance.
Do you think the problem can be with the foreign key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using only laravel/laravel package it only enables you to access only 3 table with hasOneThrough or hasManyThrough relations.

To achieve what you want or what atleast i think you're asking can be done with help of staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep packages.

For Laravel 8:
`composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep:"^1.13"`

For Laravel 9:
`composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep:"^1.7"`

Then,

In Your model :

```
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;
```

and include in your Model class by:

```
use HasRelationships;
```

Then in your model method do hasOneDeep or hasManyDeep according to usage:

```
return $this->hasOneDeep('Model_Name_You_Want_To_Access_Through', ['Model_Access_Via1', 'Model_Access_Via2'], ['ForeignKeyOf_Model_Access_Via1', 'ForeignKeyOf_Model_Access_Via2', 'ForeignKeyOf_Model_Name_You_Want_To_Access_Through']);
```

This can keep going on but remember you have to provide through array according to structure.

For references:

https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

**Option 2:**

In your ExamId Model:
You will need to create some relations to access questions, From ExamId model so we will use QuestionCategory Models and access everything through it.

ExamId may have multiple QuestionCategory (hasMany)

and QuestionCategory will have multiple questions (hasMany)

so in your ExamId Model:

```
public function getQCategory()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\QuestionCategory')->with('getQuestion');
}
```

In your Question Category Model:

```
 public function getQuestion()
 {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Question');
 }
```

In your controller:

```
 $exam = ExamId::with('getQCategory')->find($id);
```

now `$exam` will contain ExamId, Categories and Questions.

Comment: By using this you can call operations from top level of database structure.

Comment: Ok thanks. So with only laravel we can't make this? We need use a addon?

Comment: yes you can achieve only one through relation in normal laravel eloquent say Evaluation->ExamId->questionCategory only but this package enables you to go multi level through many models as much as you like but those must be linked with foreign keys as usual.

Comment: @Chrisdev I have updated code please check option 2 as well if that suits you.

Comment: No I have an error with the $id.
And for the addon that's work but I have another problem. 
It shows me the questions fine but the answers are not related.
I post for you the screenshot so you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

So for more precision, here is exactly what I want via screens.

So this is my complete function :

```
public function testtheorique($session){
        $eval = Evaluation::find($session);
        $caces = $eval->caces_cat;
        $theorique = $eval->theorique;
        $questioncat = $theorique->examcategory;

        $categories = QuestionCategorie::with(['categoryQuestions' => function ($query) {
            $query->inRandomOrder()
                ->with(['reponse' => function ($query) {
                    $query->inRandomOrder();
                }]);
        }])
        ->whereHas('categoryQuestions')
        ->get();

    return view('session.theorique', compact('categories', 'caces'))
    ->with('eval', $eval);
    }
```

So when I make a dd($eval) I have this :

[Evaluation Model with relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEzcY.png)

[Relation with TestTheorique](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYqRg.png)

[Then Relation with QuestionCategorie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeOpN.png)

[Details of QuestionCategorie without the relation with Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utzF0.png)

But I wrote this to try $categories and I have my Questions with the QuestionCategory and Response relation.
This is the screenshot from dd($categories)

[Screen of dd($categories)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAxAC.png)

[Detail of QuestionCategorie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RggCY.png)

[Detail of Relation from QuestionCategorie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OavN.png)

[Detail Question with Response relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK3o7.png)

But it's not good because I have all the questions that appear from the database and not the ones that are part of the TestTheorique session.

So I want have one Session of Evaluation.
This session have one TestTheorique (Examid),
Then, this test with several QuestioCategorie, which has several Question with Response.

Comment: Will send complete code in few hours.

Comment: @Sumitkumar That's good, I find it. You gave me part of the answer I needed.
I post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it's solved !
So this is what I maked.

In my TestTheorique Model, I changed this line like this :

```
public function examcategory(){
    return $this->hasMany(QuestionCategorie::class, 'exam_id')->with('getQuestion');
}
```

to make the relation with QuestionCategorie and select the getQuestion function. In my QuestionCategorie Model I add this :

```
 public function getQuestion(){
    return $this->hasMany(Question::class, 'category_id', 'id')->with('reponse');
}
```

}

to make the relation with Question and select the reponse function. In my Question Model I add this :

```
public function reponse()
{
    return $this->hasMany(QuestionReponse::class, 'question_id', 'id');
}
```

And now it works. If I did a dd($eval) I have all the session data displayed and not all the questions recorded in the database.

I really want to thank [Sumit Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11545457/sumit-kumar) for his help, he gave me part of the answer.

Now I continue my dev.